# Some websites can't be reached(occasionally)

Tags: network-manager, internet, dns

I occasionally(5-10 times a day) face this issue. Some of the websites are not reachable and I get the following screen.

[image]

Here are a few things related to this problem.

1. This happens with some website, not all. For example, it is very common with Wikipedia and some other websites I frequently visit.
2. This is not specific to any browser. I have tried chrome, brave, and firefox. All browsers have the same problem.
3. This issue solves automatically after 2-4 minutes. I just have to try refreshing the page a few times and the site then loads.
4. I have 3 different versions of Ubuntu installed(2 Desktop computers, one with dual boot). The problem exists in all of them: Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, and Ubuntu 20.04 respectively.
5. My friend using Windows OS in the same network has never faced this issue.
6. This problem exists in both Wi-Fi and Ethernet connections.

While browsing the websites, it isn't a major issue. However while running some scripts which has to download files from different sources, it becomes a major issue because the script fails frequently due to this problem.

What could be the solution for this? Thank you.

**Update**: Here is the output of `tracepath www.ebay.com`

[image]

Output of ping [www.ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com)

[image]

Comment: Are you on DSL?

Comment: @heynnema I am on Optical Fibre connection.

Comment: Install `iputils-tracepath` then do `tracepath www.ebay.com` and edit your question with the results.

Comment: @heynnema updated.

Comment: It looks like you're problem may be external to your computer. Show me `ping www.ebay.com` for about 20 pings.

Comment: @heynnema Added the output of ping in the question.

Comment: Power OFF your router AND fibre modem. Count to 15. Re-plug the modem first. Count to 20. Re-plug the router. count to 20, and retry the `tracepath www.ebay.com`. Show me that output if it's different than the first time.